# The NServiceBus Setup Wizard ended prematurely

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus4

I'm trying to install NServiceBus 4.0 downloaded from http://particular.net/downloads.
When I run the installer with admin rights, I get the following error.

"NServiceBus setup ended prematurely because of an error. Your system has not been modifed. To install this program at a later time, please run the installer again."

The log looks like a bunch of gibberish to me, but here is the last part of it that mentions a "FatalError"

```
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 285537
Property(S): ERROR_Q = error
Property(S): AUDIT_Q = audit
Property(S): PORT_VAL.CB8171C5_FE21_41EE_BC42_72123C0AD0F7 = 33333
Property(S): AI_LOG_CHECKBOX = 1
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 147472592
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 147187055
Property(S): AGREE_CHECKBOX = Yes
Property(S): RAVEN_PORT = 8080
Property(S): TOOLS_SH = create
Property(S): SAMPLES_SH = create
Property(S): BINARIES_SH = create
Property(S): COMPANYNAME = Member Company of the AEGON Group
Property(S): InfoIcon = info
Property(S): AI_SETUPEXEPATH_ORIGINAL = C:\Users\mastewart\Downloads\Particular.NServiceBus-4.0.2.exe
Property(S): VersionNT = 601
Property(S): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(S): AI_EXTERNALUIUNINSTALLERNAME = Particular.NServiceBus-4.0.2.exe
Property(S): InputCtrlFont = {\InputCtrlFont}
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameBottomLeft = frame_bottom_left.bmp
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameTopMidInactive = frame_top_mid_inactive.bmp
Property(S): ProductCode = {6D0463B9-5EDA-4709-ABCD-9FE27CBEDFDF}
Property(S): AI_CF_SysMinDown = sys_min_down.png
Property(S): AI_FRAME_NO_CAPTION_MinProgressDlg = 1
Property(S): MetroRunApplicationButton = metrorunapplicationbutton
Property(S): RepairIcon = repairic
Property(S): TRB_INFO_REG_VALUE = 0
Property(S): ButtonText_Decline = &Decline
Property(S): ProductNameForSplash = {\ProductNameForSplash}
Property(S): WindowsType9XDisplay = Windows 9x/ME
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameTopRight = frame_top_right.bmp
Property(S): AI_CONTROL_VISUAL_STYLE = 2960685;4276545;6776679;16176031
Property(S): AI_FINDEXE_TITLE = Select the installation package for NServiceBus
Property(S): AI_ThemeStyle = default
Property(S): ARPPRODUCTICON = NServiceBus.exe
Property(S): BackButton = backbutton
Property(S): HyperlinkFont = {\MetroLink}
Property(S): Manufacturer = Particular Software Ltd.
Property(S): UpDirIcon = Up
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameRightInactive = frame_right_inactive.bmp
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameTopLeftInactive = frame_top_left_inactive.bmp
Property(S): AI_PRODUCTNAME_ARP = Particular Software NServiceBus v4.0.2
Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(S): RunApplicationButton = runapplicationbutton
Property(S): ViewReadMeButton = viewreadmebutton
Property(S): CtrlEvtRepairing = Repairing
Property(S): CtrlEvtremoves = removes
Property(S): PROMPTROLLBACKCOST = P
Property(S): WindowsTypeNTDisplay = Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000
Property(S): AI_MINDOTNETVERSION = 4.0
Property(S): ButtonText_Finish = &Finish
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameTopMid = frame_top_mid.bmp
Property(S): ARPCOMMENTS = This installer database contains the logic and data required to install NServiceBus.
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameLeftInactive = frame_left_inactive.bmp
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameRight = frame_right.bmp
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameTopLeft = frame_top_left.bmp
Property(S): AI_UNINSTALLER = C:\ProgramData\Caphyon\Advanced Installer\{6D0463B9-5EDA-4709-ABCD-9FE27CBEDFDF}\Particular.NServiceBus-4.0.2.exe
Property(S): ButtonText_OK = OK
Property(S): ErrorDialog = ErrorDlg
Property(S): WhiteBackround = whitebackground
Property(S): metroinstallbutton = metroinstallbutton
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameBottomRightInactive = frame_bottom_right_inactive.bmp
Property(S): AI_FRAME_NO_CAPTION_PrepareDlg = 1
Property(S): ProductName = NServiceBus
Property(S): AI_BTN_NO_CORNER_SCALING_AgreeInstall = 4
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameBottomMid = frame_bottom_mid.bmp
Property(S): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(S): ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT = 1
Property(S): AppLogoIcon = NServiceBus_Logowhite.png
Property(S): Text_Install = Install
Property(S): CtrlEvtRemoving = Removing
Property(S): MY_VERSION = 4.0
Property(S): AI_COLOR_DISABLED_TEXT = 1644825
Property(S): ButtonText_Reset = &Reset
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameLeft = frame_left.bmp
Property(S): AI_CF_TITLE_TEXT_STYLE = {\CfTitleFont}
Property(S): EnableUserControl = 1
Property(S): ProductVersion = 4.0.2
Property(S): AI_CF_SysMinInactive = sys_min_inactive.png
Property(S): Progress2 = installs
Property(S): checkbox = checkbox
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameBottomRight = frame_bottom_right.bmp
Property(S): AI_CF_SYS_BTNS_XPOS = 16
Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = OLDPRODUCTS;AI_NEWERPRODUCTFOUND;AI_SETUPEXEPATH;SETUPEXEDIR
Property(S): WindowsTypeNT = Windows NT 4.0, Windows NT 4.0 Service Pack 1, Windows NT 4.0 Service Pack 2, Windows NT 4.0 Service Pack 3, Windows NT 4.0 Service Pack 4, Windows NT 4.0 Service Pack 5, Windows NT 4.0 Service Pack 6, Windows 2000, Windows 2000 Service Pack 1, Windows 2000 Service Pack 2, Windows 2000 Service Pack 3, Windows 2000 Service Pack 4
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameTopRightInactive = frame_top_right_inactive.bmp
Property(S): Background = background
Property(S): ButtonText_Return = &Return
Property(S): AI_BTN_LINEAR_BORDER_SCALING_AgreeInstall = yes
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameBottomMidInactive = frame_bottom_mid_inactive.bmp
Property(S): AI_CF_SysCloseDown = sys_close_down.png
Property(S): AI_ImagesColor = metroblack
Property(S): ExclamationIcon = exclamic
Property(S): WindowsType9X = Windows 9x/ME
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameBottomLeftInactive = frame_bottom_left_inactive.bmp
Property(S): AI_CF_SysCloseNormal = sys_close_normal.png
Property(S): AI_Init_PatchWelcomeDlg = [AI_ButtonText_Next_Orig]:[ButtonText_Next]:AI_PATCH|[ButtonText_Next]:[[AI_CommitButton]]:AI_PATCH|[AI_Text_Next_Orig]:[Text_Next]:AI_PATCH|[Text_Next]:[Text_Install]:AI_PATCH
Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 3
Property(S): CtrlEventRemoved = removed
Property(S): AI_CommitButton = ButtonText_Install
Property(S): AI_HIDE_CAPTION_ICON_AND_TEXT = 1
Property(S): browsebutton = browsebutton
Property(S): AI_CF_DRAG_FROM_ANY_POINT = 1
Property(S): AiPrerequisitesColums = PrereqLabel,PrereqReq,PrereqFound,PrereqAction
Property(S): ButtonText_Browse = Br&owse...
Property(S): NewDirIcon = New
Property(S): AI_HIDE_CAPTION_ICON_AND_TEXT_ALL = 1
Property(S): ButtonText_Cancel = Cancel
Property(S): OptionsLogoIcon = optionslogoicon
Property(S): metrobuttonimage = metrobuttonimage
Property(S): ButtonText_Exit = &Exit
Property(S): CtrlEvtrepairs = repairs
Property(S): DefaultUIFont = DlgFont8
Property(S): AI_CHECK_BOX_IMAGES = checkbox_for_list_ctrls
Property(S): ButtonText_Ignore = &Ignore
Property(S): ModifyButton = modify.png
Property(S): RemoveIcon = removico
Property(S): AI_CF_SysMinNormal = sys_min_normal.png
Property(S): ButtonText_No = &No
Property(S): SubTitleStyle = {\SubTitle}
Property(S): CtrlEvtChanging = Changing
Property(S): Text_Next = Next
Property(S): AI_CF_SysCloseHot = sys_close_hot.png
Property(S): ButtonText_Resume = &Resume
Property(S): ButtonText_Yes = &Yes
Property(S): MetroInstallButtonFont = {\MetroInstallButton}
Property(S): Wizard = Setup Wizard
Property(S): ButtonText_Retry = &Retry
Property(S): PrintIcon = printico
Property(S): AI_CF_SYS_BTNS_YPOS = 16
Property(S): ButtonText_Accept = &Accept
Property(S): DlgTitleFont = {\DlgFontBold8}
Property(S): MetroPrintButton = print.png
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameCaptionInactive = frame_caption_inactive.bmp
Property(S): CtrlEventConfigured = configured
Property(S): CtrlEvtchanges = changes
Property(S): InstallModeComplete = Complete
Property(S): WaitLogoItem = waitlogoicon
Property(S): InstallModeCustom = Custom
Property(S): InstallerIcon = insticon
Property(S): Finish1 = installed
Property(S): InstallModeTypical = Typical
Property(S): TypicalButton = modify.png
Property(S): AiEarlyValidate = 1
Property(S): ButtonText_Back = &Back
Property(S): InstallLogoIcon = installlogoicon
Property(S): Setup = Setup
Property(S): AI_EXE_EXTRACTION_FOLDER = [AppDataFolder]Particular Software Ltd.\NServiceBus 4.0.2\install
Property(S): Progress1 = Installing
Property(S): AI_CF_SysMinHot = sys_min_hot.png
Property(S): ButtonText_Next = &Next
Property(S): AI_CF_FrameCaption = frame_caption.bmp
Property(S): AI_CF_SHARP_CORNERS = 1
Property(S): AI_FrameBtnsColor = metroblack
Property(S): AI_ThemeStyleEx = border
Property(S): AI_BUILD_NAME = DefaultBuild
Property(S): AI_CF_SysCloseInactive = sys_close_inactive.png
Property(S): AI_CF_TYPE = 1
Property(S): AI_FrameColor = metroblack
Property(S): AI_TREE_CHECK_BOX_IMAGES = checkbox_for_ctrls
Property(S): CompleteSetupIcon = completi
Property(S): AiStyleConditions = |DefaultUIFont;AI_ThemeStyle="default":DlgFont8;AI_ThemeStyle="metrored":DefaultTextWhite;AI_ThemeStyle="metrowhite":DefaultTextBlack;|HyperlinkFont;AI_ThemeStyle="default":{\MetroLink};AI_ThemeStyle="metrored":{\MetroLinkLightRed};AI_ThemeStyle="metrowhite":{\MetroLink};|MetroButtonText;AI_ThemeStyle="default":{\ImageButton};AI_ThemeStyle="metrored":{\MetroButtonTextWhite};AI_ThemeStyle="metrowhite":{\MetroButtonTextBlack};|InputCtrlFont;AI_ThemeStyle="default":{\InputCtrlFontGray};AI_ThemeStyle="metrored":{\InputCtrlFont};AI_ThemeStyle="metrowhite":{\InputCtrlFontBlack};|BrandingStyle;AI_ThemeStyle="default":{\BrandingStyleGray};AI_ThemeStyle="metrored":{\BrandingStyle};AI_ThemeStyle="metrowhite":{\BrandingStyleLightGray};|SubTitleStyle;AI_ThemeStyle="default":{\SubTitle};AI_ThemeStyle="metrored":{\SubTitleWhite};AI_ThemeStyle="metrowhite":{\SubTitleBlack};|SubnoteFontStyle;AI_ThemeStyle="default":{\SubnoteFont};AI_ThemeStyle="metrored":{\SubnoteFontWhite};AI_ThemeStyle="metrowhite":{\SubnoteFontGray};|ProductNameForSplash;AI_ThemeStyle="default":{\ProductNameForSplash};AI_ThemeStyle="metrored":{\ProductNameForSplash};AI_ThemeStyle="metrowhite":{\ProductNameForSplashDark};|ManufacturerFont;AI_ThemeStyle="default":{\Manufacturer};AI_ThemeStyle="metrored":{\Manufacturer};AI_ThemeStyle="metrowhite":{\ManufacturerGreen};|MetroInstallButtonFont;AI_ThemeStyle="default":{\MetroInstallButton};AI_ThemeStyle="metrored":{\MetroInstallButton};AI_ThemeStyle="metrowhite":{\MetroInstallButtonGreen};
Property(S): CustomSetupIcon = custicon
Property(S): MetroButtonText = {\ImageButton}
Property(S): SubnoteFontStyle = {\SubnoteFont}
Property(S): ManufacturerFont = {\Manufacturer}
Property(S): AI_PACKAGE_TYPE = Intel
Property(S): Intel = 6
Property(S): BrandingStyle = {\BrandingStyle}
Property(S): LaunchApplicationButtonText = Run the application
Property(S): AI_Init_InstallDlg = [InstallDlg]:1:AI_INSTALL
Property(S): ViewReadMeButtonText = View Readme File
Property(S): NextCancelButtons = nextcancelbuttons
Property(S): MsiLogFileLocation = C:\Temp\NServiceBus.LOG
Property(S): AIEXTERNALUI = 5
Property(S): AI_SETUPEXEPATH = C:\Users\mastewart\Downloads\Particular.NServiceBus-4.0.2.exe
Property(S): CustomActionData = Particular.Management
Property(S): ARPINSTALLLOCATION = C:\Program Files (x86)\Particular Software\NServiceBus\v4.0\
Property(S): AI_DOTNET40_SEARCH = #1
Property(S): POWERSHELL = 2.0
Property(S): POWERSHELL_EXE = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Property(S): APPDIR.CB8171C5_FE21_41EE_BC42_72123C0AD0F7 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Particular Software\NServiceBus\v4.0\
Property(S): Management_Dir.CB8171C5_FE21_41EE_BC42_72123C0AD0F7 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Particular Software\NServiceBus\v4.0\Management\
Property(S): X64_REG.CB8171C5_FE21_41EE_BC42_72123C0AD0F7 = Management
Property(S): AI_ModuleId.CB8171C5_FE21_41EE_BC42_72123C0AD0F7 = CB8171C5_FE21_41EE_BC42_72123C0AD0F7
Property(S): WindowsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\
Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 1
Property(S): WindowsBuild = 7601
Property(S): VersionNT64 = 601
Property(S): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(S): SETUPEXEDIR = C:\Users\mastewart\Downloads\
Property(S): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0
Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): PRIMARYFOLDER = APPDIR
Property(S): EXE_CMD_LINE = /exenoupdates  /exelang 0 /noprereqs   
Property(S): AI_MORE_CMD_LINE = 1
Property(S): ADDLOCAL = DTC,PrepMachine,MSMQ,ManagementPack,NServiceBus,Tools,Samples
Property(S): CLIENTPROCESSID = 5736
Property(S): SECONDSEQUENCE = 1
Property(S): ROOTDRIVE = C:\
Property(S): EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(S): USERNAME = Member Company of the AEGON Group
Property(S): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(S): ProductState = -1
Property(S): PackageCode = {C1994255-D8EF-43DA-9924-C444441F3CB8}
Property(S): System64Folder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\
Property(S): SystemFolder = C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\
Property(S): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(S): TempFolder = C:\Temp\
Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(S): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(S): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(S): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(S): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\mastewart\AppData\Roaming\
Property(S): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\mastewart\Favorites\
Property(S): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\mastewart\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(S): PersonalFolder = \\wlrn5200c1\wlr_tebusers01\mastewart\
Property(S): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\mastewart\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(S): RecentFolder = C:\Users\mastewart\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(S): SendToFolder = C:\Users\mastewart\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(S): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(S): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(S): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\mastewart\AppData\Local\
Property(S): MyPicturesFolder = \\wlrn5200c1\wlr_tebusers01\mastewart\My Pictures\
Property(S): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(S): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(S): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(S): FontsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\
Property(S): GPTSupport = 1
Property(S): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(S): Msix64 = 6
Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 8073
Property(S): VirtualMemory = 11923
Property(S): AdminUser = 1
Property(S): MsiTrueAdminUser = 1
Property(S): LogonUser = MaStewart
Property(S): UserSID = S-1-5-21-2380165290-1749897186-383349493-298796
Property(S): UserLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ComputerName = WLR1FTDHS1
Property(S): SystemLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ScreenX = 1024
Property(S): ScreenY = 768
Property(S): CaptionHeight = 22
Property(S): BorderTop = 1
Property(S): BorderSide = 1
Property(S): TextHeight = 16
Property(S): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(S): ColorBits = 32
Property(S): TTCSupport = 1
Property(S): Time = 16:18:23
Property(S): Date = 8/8/2013
Property(S): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.1
Property(S): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.1.7601.17514
Property(S): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(S): Privileged = 1
Property(S): DATABASE = C:\WINDOWS\Installer\5c1327.msi
Property(S): OriginalDatabase = C:\Users\mastewart\AppData\Roaming\Particular Software Ltd\NServiceBus 4.0.2\install\NServiceBus.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 5
Property(S): Preselected = 1
Property(S): ARP_ICON_PATH = C:\WINDOWS\Installer\{6D0463B9-5EDA-4709-ABCD-9FE27CBEDFDF}\NServiceBus.exe
Property(S): USR_ADMINISTRATOR = ldsksup
Property(S): USR_GUEST = ldskgst
Property(S): GRP_DOMAIN_USERS = None
Property(S): GRP_EVERYONE = Everyone
Property(S): USR_NETWORK_SERVICE = NETWORK SERVICE
Property(S): GRP_BACKUP_OPS = Backup Operators
Property(S): GRP_ADMINISTRATORS = Administrators
Property(S): GRP_USERS = Users
Property(S): GRP_GUESTS = Guests
Property(S): GRP_POWER_USERS = Power Users
Property(S): GRP_REPLICATOR = Replicator
Property(S): GRP_REMOTE_DESKTOP_USERS = Remote Desktop Users
Property(S): GRP_NETWORK_CONFIGURATION_OPS = Network Configuration Operators
Property(S): GRP_MONITORING_USERS = Performance Monitor Users
Property(S): GRP_LOGGING_USERS = Performance Log Users
Property(S): WindowsLibrariesFolder = C:\Users\mastewart\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\
Property(S): SavedGamesFolder = C:\Users\mastewart\Saved Games\
Property(S): PublicDocumentsFolder = C:\Users\Public\Documents\
Property(S): AI_PrereqsFulfilled = 1
Property(S): AI_SERVICE_STATE = Not Found
Property(S): TRIAL_DATE = 08/08/2013
Property(S): CostingComplete = 1
Property(S): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumePath = C:
Property(S): SOURCEDIR = C:\Users\mastewart\AppData\Roaming\Particular Software Ltd\NServiceBus 4.0.2\install\
Property(S): SourcedirProduct = {6D0463B9-5EDA-4709-ABCD-9FE27CBEDFDF}
Property(S): ProductToBeRegistered = 1
MSI (s) (A0:54) [16:18:23:601]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (A0:50) [16:18:23:604]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (A0:50) [16:18:23:604]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (A0:50) [16:18:23:604]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (A0:50) [16:18:23:604]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (A0:50) [16:18:23:605]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (A0:50) [16:18:23:605]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (A0:50) [16:18:23:605]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (A0:50) [16:18:23:606]: Restoring environment variables
MSI (s) (A0:50) [16:18:23:606]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (s) (A0:90) [16:18:23:606]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
MSI (c) (68:58) [16:18:23:607]: Back from server. Return value: 1603
MSI (c) (68:58) [16:18:23:607]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (68:58) [16:18:23:607]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 16:18:23: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
=== Verbose logging stopped: 8/8/2013  16:18:23 ===
    Action ended 14:50:29: ProgressDlg. Return value 1.
    MSI (c) (10:18) [14:50:29:647]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: AI_TempFile 
    MSI (c) (10:18) [14:50:29:647]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: AI_TempFile 4: SELECT `Property` FROM `AI_TempFile` 
    MSI (c) (10:18) [14:50:29:647]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: AI_PreRequisite 
    MSI (c) (10:18) [14:50:29:647]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: AI_PreRequisite 4: SELECT `RetValPropName` FROM `AI_PreRequisite` 
    MSI (c) (10:18) [14:50:29:647]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: AI_XmlLocator 
    MSI (c) (10:18) [14:50:29:647]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: AI_XmlLocator 4: SELECT `Property` FROM `AI_XmlLocator` 
    MSI (c) (10:18) [14:51:34:717]: Doing action: FatalError
    Action 14:51:34: FatalError. 
    Action start 14:51:34: FatalError.
    Action ended 14:59:36: FatalError. Return value 1.
    MSI (c) (10:18) [14:59:36:591]: Doing action: AI_SHOW_LOG
    Action 14:59:36: AI_SHOW_LOG. 
    Action start 14:59:36: AI_SHOW_LOG.
    MSI (c) (10:38) [14:59:36:593]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Temp\MSIFE1.tmp, Entrypoint: LaunchLogFile
    Action ended 14:59:36: AI_SHOW_LOG. Return value 1.
    MSI (c) (10:18) [14:59:36:720]: Doing action: FatalError
    Action 14:59:36: FatalError. 
    Action start 14:59:36: FatalError.
    Action ended 14:59:36: FatalError. Return value 2.
    MSI (c) (10:18) [14:59:36:720]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Environment 3: -2147287038 
    MSI (c) (10:FC) [14:59:36:724]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
    MSI (c) (10:34) [14:59:36:724]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
    === Verbose logging stopped: 8/8/2013  14:59:36 ===
```

Comment: Could you provide a few more lines above the snippet you provided?

Comment: I couldn't add the entire log due to it's size. But there's quite a bit of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are aware that the installer is failing to install on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.
Are you using any of these OSs?

If you are, try to install MSMQ manually before running the installer.

Also, on the log of the installer do a search for "value 3", if you find it, the error should be just above it.

Comment: John, I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64bit.

I installed MSMQ manually then I ran the installer. During the installation I was prompted to restart my machine. After a restart, I ran the installer again and it looks like it installed successfully.

The installer is supposed to install MSMQ automatically, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is but for some reason it fails sometimes, are you able to email me the log of the first failure?

Comment: Sorry John, I don't have the log anymore.

Comment: John, what log(s) are you looking for, I have a VM set up (win7 enterprise x64) where this is currently failing.  It seems to be something recent that is causing this in win7, because I had it working before.

Answer (score 0):

To add further detail to the accepted answer...

For NServiceBus 4.0.5 on Windows 8, the secret is to install only MSMQ Server Core. Make sure you don't install any of its sub-components. i.e. don't check HTTP support, triggers, multi-casting, or Active directory.
And also don't install MSMQ DCOM proxy.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; 
Build from release source.

Slightly longer version:
The answer is not to install MSMQ (unless you want to use MSMQ), the answer is not to use the installer.  I ended up building from the source (for version 4.0.4) and then using the PowerShell commandlets to install RavenDB (which it turns out is also unnecessary in our use case, but most people will need it).

Ultimately I've deployed the code using NServiceBus to a virtual server running Win 2008 without the installer or the PowerShell commandlets, but this is for a PoC using RabbitMQ that doesn't require any of the persistence that RavenDB is used for by default and which is configured to use 'InMemory' settings where needed.